# How to can append the value from txt file to the Qlist

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qlist

How I can to insert the value from txt file in to the Qlist...

```
QList<QString> list_StRead;
list_StRead.insert();
```

I can sorting txt file ... its mean that my file is a line by line. than after the insert to the Qlist I want to write in to Qtabelewidget. How I must to do?? u must to be completely understand. see the img file

[image]

tnx for all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code.
Please try it. (Not tested, code written in notepad. excuse me any syntax errors).

```
//Your list
QList<QString> list_StRead;

//Text stream object read data and insert in list.
QTextStream in(&file);
   while (!in.atEnd())
   {
      QString line = in.readLine(); //read one line at a time
      list_StRead.push_back(line);
   }


//loop your list 
for(int i =0; i<list_StRead.size(); i++)
{

//Add by create your tablewidget item and append it.
YourTableWidget->setItem(rowNumber,colNumber,new  QTableWidgetItem(list_StRead.at(i)))


}
```